# To restrict GitLab's pipelines only for master branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are running a private project in GitLab instance (version 14.6) free edition.

Our scenario is like this ->

1. For each network engineer we will create a branch and we will give it to them. All engineers will be given the "Developer" role.
2. An administrator account will have access to the "master" branch.
3. No "Developer" user should push/merge in the master branch. They just can create a merge request.
4. In the master branch, the usual git-ci yml file will be edited obviously by only administrators. Also, the pipelines for master branch commits will only be executed by admins.
5. The master branch's git-ci yml file will obviously be present in other branches too. But when edited by "Developers" in those branches, those shouldn't be created as pipelines. In fact, it should be - CI/CD -> pipelines -> *Only the pipelines for master branch commits should exist here*

Can someone please suggest the settings template for the above guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

So you can restrict jobs to only run on the master branch using rules
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules

e.g.

```
my_job:
    script:
        - echo "hello"
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
```

Comment: But that script is available in the developer branch also. For those also pipelines are being created. We don't want users who are in the developer role to execute the pipeline. But here, they can push into their branches and can create/run pipelines. How to restrict that.